Need assistance with the fireEvent click event
Having an issue with the fireEvent.click returning control to the test
        const addReplacementCiraButton = within(componentContainer).getAllByTestId('AddIcon')[0];
        act(() => {
          fireEvent.click(addReplacementCiraButton);
        });
        // Add new replacement ingredient information to new inputs
        //   Ingredient
        const element1 = await mealEditForm.findAllByLabelText('Ingredient');

After the test is run I never get to the last line. I am on the latest version of react/react-dom 18.3.1 and
    "@testing-library/dom": "^10.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",

This all used to work before I upgraded to the latest major versions of the libraries specified. Any help would be appreciated.

Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
